# Admob using AD_UNIT_ID

Tags: android, admob

I need to find my AD_UNIT_ID for the line:

```
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID ="";
```

So can someone give me an example for an AD_UNIT_ID, i mean how it should look like?

So is it this one:

ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/yyyyyyyyyy

or only the yyyyyyyyyy?

Comment: No, that is your publisher ID, create an AD Unit and you'll see it.  All of mine have no hyphens in and certainly don't start with `pub-`

Comment: create an app in Admob dashboard. It will generate a unique id for your app. The app need not be a published one.

Comment: @LeeArmstrong So when im going to my banner I find this ,is it this one: 
ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/yyyyyyyyyy
OR only the yyyyyyyyyy?

Comment: @intrepidkarthi Can you see edit plz? I want to test the ads and I don't know if my id is good .. I already created an app

Comment: first one is the adunit id

Answer (score 2):

Ad Unit Id is a unique ID for each Admob users.

To find the ad unit ID, once you are logged in [Admob](https://www.admob.com/login?_cd=1&_ga=1.115868486.170074277.1402299474#utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=ww-ww-et-admob2), click the Monetize tab. Click All apps from the left-hand side and select an app. The ad unit ID is under the ad unit name.

If you dont have one, here is how to create an Ad Unit ID from scratch to end. [Create an ad unit](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3052638?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I have just created an AD_UNIT_ID myself and its in the **ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/NNNNNNNNNN** format, ads are being properly displayed in the app.

U can see more clarification in [Google Mobile Ads SDK FAQ](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/?hl=en)